# JS ES5: Transform an object to match required syntax using pre-ES6 javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, ecmascript-5, google-datalayer

I am web analyst for an ecommerce store and I haven't got access to code. All I can use is Tag Manager (GTM) which allows me to use custom JS code.
I need to transform a JavaScript "cart" object so that it matches a syntax required by Google Analytics 4. In this example there are 2 items in the cart.
There is a dataLayer for Adobe Analytics on the page, which has the following structure:

```
cart {
    "itemNo": ["14347941","14508712"],
    "itemQuant": [1,1],
    "itemPrice": ["2,180.33","28.93"],
    "uniqItemCount": 2,
    "totItemCount": 2
}
```

I need it to look this way:

```
items[
  {
   item_id: "14347941",
   quantity: 1,
   price:  2180.33
  },
  {
   item_id: "14508712",
   quantity: 1,
   price:  28.93
  }
]
```

Every product is a separate object in an array of items.
Additional difficulty: I can only use ES5, as ES6+ is not supported by GTM, so not let and const keywords etc.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` with a callback `function` which is supported in ES5:

```js
var cart = {
    "itemNo": ["14347941","14508712"],
    "itemQuant": [1,1],
    "itemPrice": ["2,180.33","28.93"],
    "uniqItemCount": 2,
    "totItemCount": 2
}

var items = cart.itemNo.map(function (item_id, i) {
    return {
        item_id: item_id,
        quantity: cart.itemQuant[i],
        price: +cart.itemPrice[i].replace(/,/g, "")
    };
});

console.log(items);
```

The call to `replace` is used to remove the thousand separator(s) from the price strings, and `+` is the unary plus operator to convert the string to a number type.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. In the meantime I figured out such an alternative solution myself:

`function(){
    var items = [];
    var adobe_cart = dataLayer.cart;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < adobe_cart.uniqItemCount; i++) {   
      items[i] = {
            'item_id': adobe_cart.itemNo[i],
            'price': adobe_cart.itemPrice[i].replace.replace(',',''),
            'quantity': adobe_cart.itemQuant[i]
    }
}
    return items;
   } `

Can you say that one approach is better than the other? Taking into consideration performance, code purity, readability, best practices etc.

Comment: JavaScript offers many ways to do such transformations. What is better in terms of "purity, readability, best practices" is a matter of opinion. There are different schools of thought. For performance, a plain `for` loop will most often win the battle. But for something relatively small like a Cart, this is irrelevant. One will not find millions of entries in a cart. Using an array method like `reduce` is what followers of the *functional programming* paradigm will prefer.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: `replace(',', '')` will only replace **one** comma. If it is possible to have a price that exceeds a million, then this can become a problem. Also, the repetition of `replace` is probably an unintended typo.